My image disappears when inside a motion.div - Remix.js
I am using Remix.js for a project and working on a component where an image should animate into view using Framer Motion. However, the image does not display when wrapped in motion.div. Below is the relevant code snippet:
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import welcomeCssRef from "./welcome.css";

export const links = () => [{ rel: "stylesheet", href: welcomeCssRef }];


const fromRightVariants = {
  offscreen: { x: 300, opacity: 0 },
  onscreen: {
    x: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      type: "spring",
      bounce: 0.4,
      duration: 0.8
    }
  }
};

export default function WelcomeSection() {
  return (
    <section className="section first_sec">
      <div className="section_left">
        <div className="hero_desc_section">
          <h2>A better way to trade</h2>
          <p>
            StellarX is a powerful decentralized trading platform built on
            the Stellar network. Connect your wallet and start trading every
            asset class imaginable in seconds. Access AMMs to earn passive
            income, on & off ramp with ease.
          </p>
          <button>Explore StellarX</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <motion.div
        className="section_right"
        initial="offscreen"
        whileInView="onscreen"
        viewport={{ once: true, amount: 0.8 }}
      >
        <motion.div variants={fromRightVariants}>
          <img
            src="https://www.stellarx.com/bf96c308f0a32e9c4456.png"
            alt="StellarX desktop"
          />
        </motion.div>
      </motion.div>
    </section>
  );
}


What I've Tried

Importing CSS: I tried importing the CSS file using import "./welcome.css"; instead of linking it. This made the image display and the animation work.
Replacing motion.div with div: When I replace motion.div with a regular div, the image shows up but the animation does not work.

Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.
